Relative energy vs. magnitude of spectrum
BACKGROUND
I have several spectra, one each 32 ms, each 256 bins 0-4 kHz, sampled at 16 kHz.
I listen for recorded sounds of 32 spectra each, ie. 1024 ms. I pick out the three strongest magnitudes, but lower the triggering sensitivity by critically "looking around" in the magnitude spectrum. I only have generic code, nothing fine tuned for any particular type of sound.
Now I thought I should also look at the total energy, either of the other peaks, or every bin as such. To avoid some cases of false alarms, like from a vacuum cleaner that I think must use "audible" PWM(?) to regulate the speed. Then do the ratio of the energy of the three most powerful peaks v. the energy of the rest. But I need more filtering.
I am working with the magnitude √(re*re+im*im) for this. But the energy is the inner part here: re*re+im*im.
QUESTION
Would I have any advantage of dealing with the proper energy instead of using magnitudes, for this ratio? This is an embedded application where I want to store as few arrays as possible.
Like (m1+m2+m3)/(m_the_rest) vs. (e1+e2+e3)/(e_the_rest)?

What is your goal here? You describe snippets of an algorithm but you don't tell us what the algorithm is supposed to be doing and what the specific requirements are.

To further minimise false alarms. I record sounds, like a door bell, and listen for it. I then use three peaks from the recorded door bell and then compare, sliding 32 spectra over one sec. Triggering means alarm by some kind of correlation of those three. Now I want to view a spectrum as a whole, not the missing peaks, but the total number of peaks' "energy". Finding an easy way to say "this was not an alarm", there's too much noise - by doing some kind of energy treatment. That algorithm I now try to find, hence the qusetion.
